# Use of participle 'considered' in the sense 'currently under consideration'

Tags: meaning, word-choice, phrase-requests

I'm writing a research paper and I have to use a certain approximation in my calculations. Can I write a phrase like this?
 *In the considered approximation these terms may be neglected.*  This means that in the approximation I am using thoughout the paper, I may ignore certain terms in my equations. I'm specifically asking about the use of the past participle 'considered'. I have other versions like 'approximation considered' or 'approximation being considered'. Are they better or worse, or should I try something entirely different to convey the meaning?

Comment: Either that or just *In this approximation…* work fine. The only think I'd change would be to say the terms *are negligible*; it should be easy to check similar papers in your field to see whether either wording is preferred. If this approximation is one you've created for the purposes of your paper, you should explain why, otherwise, refer them to the source.

Comment: _In this approximation_ does not always work, because it can be long after I stated what my aproximation is when I refer to it again. For instance, in the introduction I can say _We calculate things to second order in a very small parameter_ and then a few pages later _In the considered approximation..._ I guess what I meant to say was: can I refer back to something in  this way, using the word 'considered'?  Can I say in the opening paragraph _In this paper we consider a theory..._ and then a few paragraphs later _The considered theory posesses certain properties..._?